# copying a structure to char buffer

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main ()
{
   time_t  time_raw_format;
   struct tm * ptr_time;
   char *buff;
   time ( &time_raw_format);
   ptr_time = localtime ( &time_raw_format );
}
```

How to copy this to a `*buff`, return type of `ptr_time` is `struct tm*`,my actual goal is to copy system date and time to a char buffer and how to calculate the size returned by `localtime`, as `*ptr_time` is a pointer if I do `sizeof` that i get the value as 4

Comment: Are you looking for `sizeof(struct tm)`? You can also use `sizeof *ptr_time` in this case, if you prefer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can format the time into a char buffer with [`strftime()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime)

```
char buff[20];
strftime(buff, sizeof(buf), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", ptr_time);
```

`ptr_time` is a pointer, `*ptr_time` is dereferencing a pointer. `sizeof(ptr_time)` gives the value 4, on a 32 bit system. The size of `struct tm` is either `sizeof(struct tm)` or `sizeof(*ptr_time)`, which gives the size of whatever the pointer points to.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for how to put a human readable time in a string, here is a solution:

```
#include <time.h>

char *buff = asctime(ptr_time);
```

The memory for `buff` is statically allocated by `ctime` and `asctime`.

Answer (score 0):

If understand correctly, you want to convert `struct tm` to string, use [strftime()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime) for that:

```
char buf[200];
strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%c", ptr_time);
```